# Understanding the integral $\int_0^1\det(v(t),v'(t))dt$ where $v(t)$ is path in the plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, differential-equations

Let $v(t) : [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^2$ be a smooth path, and let $v' := dv/dt$. I'd like to understand what the integral:
$$I(v) := \int_0^1 \det(v(t),v'(t))dt$$
tells us about $v$, where $\det(v(t),v'(t))$ denotes the determinant of the $2\times 2$ matrix with columns $v(t),v'(t)$. For example, if $v(t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $|v(t)|$ is constant, then this is essentially the total curvature of the parametrized curve with tangent vector $v(t)$. My intuition is that $I(v)$ is some notion of "average direction" of $v$, relative to $v(0)$, and weighted by the magnitude of $v$ (e.g., if $v(t)$ lies on a 1-dim subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$, then $I(v) = 0$).

Some more specific questions are: In what way can we control $v(1)$ in terms of $v(0)$ and $I(v)$? Does anyone have any references where integrals of this type have been considered?

For some context, I believe integrals of this type show up when studying the Kodaira-Spencer map associated to a family of elliptic curves.

Answer (score 4):

This is just the Levy area. Denote $v(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, then $\operatorname{det}(v(t),v'(t))=x(t)y'(t)-x'(t)y(t).$ In this case we have

$$I(v)=\int_0^1 x(t)dy(t)-y(t)dx(t).$$

By Green-Stokes this is just twice the area swept out by the curve (with respect to the line connecting $v(0)$ and $v(1)$).

The Levy area and related objects are the central objects of study in rough paths theory.

Also, to answer your question about whether you can control $v(1)$ in terms of $I(v)$ the answer is no. Just look at the line $v(t)=t(c_1,c_2)$. In this case $I(v)=0$ but $v(1)=(c_1,c_2)$ can be anything.

Comment: Interesting! What do you mean exactly by the area swept out by the curve? (e.g., $v(t)$ can have all sorts of crazy self-intersections) Can you explain a little more how you're using Stokes' theorem here? Also, do you have a good reference for the Levy area?

Comment: It's the signed area between the origin, and the various endpoints of the curve.  i.e. think of all the line segments between $0$ and $v(t)$ for  the various values of $t$ you are considering. So if $v$ parametrized the unit circle, it would be the area of the pie whose circular boundary is parametrized by $v$.